# Sitecore Patch not working in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: patch-configuration

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 .I have overriden the ContentPredicate() method for chinese language search box drawback from Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService and i want to apply a patch for it so i have created config file under App_Config/Include folder but this patch is not working.

If i directly edit the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search the overriden method is getting called and its working but when i try to apply a patch it is not.

Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search file:

```
<register serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.ISearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" implementationType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" lifetime="Singleton"/>
           <!-- <register serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.ISearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" implementationType="SearchFeatureCustomization.CustomSearchService, SearchFeatureCustomization" lifetime="Singleton"/>-->
```

Here is my overriden code:

```
namespace SearchFeatureCustomization
{
    public class CustomSearchService : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService
    {
        protected override Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>> ContentPredicate(string content)
        {
            Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>> expression = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPage>();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            {
                return expression;
            }
            foreach (string item in content.Split().TrimAndRemoveEmpty())
            {
                string t = item;
                expression = expression.And((ContentPage i) => i.AggregatedContent.Contains(t) || i.AggregatedContent.Equals(t, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            }
            return expression;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>

      <pipelines>
        <initialize>
          <register type="SearchFeatureCustomization.CustomSearchService, SearchFeatureCustomization"
                     patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.ISearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search']" lifetime="Singleton" resolve="true"/>
        </initialize>
      </pipelines>
    
   </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

can anyone please help where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Placed you patch file under zzz folder in App_config as well

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.ISearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" implementationType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" lifetime="Singleton">
        <patch:attribute name="implementationType">SearchFeatureCustomization.CustomSearchService, SearchFeatureCustomization</patch:attribute>
    </register>
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this is giving the error as "Could not load type 'SearchFeatureCustomization.iCustomSearchService' from assembly 'SearchFeatureCustomization'." because i dont have icustomsearchservice implemented @Gatogordo

Comment: Sorry, typo with copy/paste and such.. updated and should be better now.

Comment: i added this but this patch is not calling the overridden method

Comment: Updated once more to have an actual instead patch..  that should do it. Sorry for the mix-ups.. multitasking is not a good idea ;)

Comment: @Vinaya you're walking a fine line between raising a legitimate question about how config patching works, and asking the community to do your work for you. Stay on the right side of the line, please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a patch like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
    <register serviceType="SearchFeatureCustomization.iCustomSearchService, SearchFeatureCustomization" implementationType="SearchFeatureCustomization.CustomSearchService, SearchFeatureCustomization" lifetime="Singleton" patch:before="register[@serviceType='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.ISearchService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search']"/>
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Gatogordo i dont have icustomSearchService implementation

Comment: I'll add my own answer - will be easier than editing this one which has the correct intention but some things missing as well.